# What's the preferred way of organizing execution order in Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

In our project, we have stored procedures which reference other procedures.

What is people's way of organizing it dynamically, since Liquibase simply executes in the order they are in?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way Liquibase can automatically resolve dependencies in objects like stored procedures/etc. You need to do it manually, for example, split procedures by "layers" (set of independent procedures that are required for next "layer") and execute "layers" in sequential changesets.